# How to force Cloudfront to cache static files

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, w3-total-cache

I have a WordPress site with W3 Total cache plugin installed on it.

I have configured Cloudfront CDN from the plugin. Currently when I test on GTMetrix the Cloudfront URLs does not have any Cache TTL in there.

Here is my settings:

W3TotalCache: https://nimb.ws/2go4sO

Cloudfront
[image]

I am not sure what thing is wrong here. Can anyone help me with the proper settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. Create a custom policy same as caching optimised but with min time 300000 and default 450000. Apply policy to the behavior then retest after invalidate.